# Geos projection not centered on the equator?

Tags: proj, satellite, geos

I'm working with QGIS and satellite view projections, in order to achieve something similar to the maps created by Richard Edes Harrison for *Fortune* magazine in the '40s ([reference](https://www.davidrumsey.com/luna/servlet/detail/RUMSEY~8~1~290311~90067583:The-communist-fastness-?sort=Pub_List_No_InitialSort,Pub_Date,Pub_List_No,Series_No&qvq=q:richard%20edes%20harrison;sort:Pub_List_No_InitialSort,Pub_Date,Pub_List_No,Series_No;lc:RUMSEY~8~1&mi=52&trs=127)). I have a question regarding `+proj=geos`. I'm working with QGIS 3.8.2.

- Is it possible to have a `geos` projection not centered on the Equator? Theese parameters (`+proj=geos +h=30000000.0 +lon_0=70 +sweep=y`) generates this map:

[image]

I would like to tilt the view towards the North Pole, so that Russia (outlined in red) would be more visible and centered on the view.

Comment: It sounds like you want +ob_tran. I don't know if it's supported in QGIS or not. See https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4285

Comment: OK, I will do that, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only answer the first question about the GEOS projection.

The GEOS projection displays the earth as a geostationary satellite would see it (this is where its name comes from). Geostationary satellites orbit the Earth with an orbital period that is the same as the Earth's rotational period. To be able to do  that, they are placed directly above the equator (allocated at different longitudes, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_satellites_in_geosynchronous_orbit)) at an altitude close to 36,000 km. That is the underlying reason why latitude is not included as a [GEOS projection parameters](http://geotiff.maptools.org/proj_list/geos.html). Hence to answer your question, no you cannot have a GEOS projection that is not centered on the equator.